# Question - Wordpress Better SEO integratedd than EE?

Tags: seo, google

There exist a local webdesign company that they say, that with wordpress ,every site they build with it , or passed from something else to wordpress, it worked much better as the traffic income was suddenly increasing and they are saying that this is due tot wordpress and that other CMS would not do that,

What do you believe about this ?

Answer (score 4):

No. The CMS itself has nothing to do an increase in site traffic. However, if a developer doesn't know a lot about EE, it's likely to be perceived that Wordpress caters to SEO better than EE, but this just isn't true. Credible people from both platforms have great success with each (including SEO). The CMS is just a tool people choose for one reason or another, but any good CMS will not dictate results in a search engine or how the site appears.

Comment: Hei, I posted the question on Forrst and got this reply : #actually that's true because wordpress is known by his strong taxonomie that make the SEO better his number one in SEO also in customization simply the best CMS #answer2: It has great SEO built in, partly because of the permalinks structure and partly because of the emphasis on content that comes from its origin as a blogging platform........ I'm getting confused

Comment: Out of the box, Wordpress will provide better SEO results, yes. But that doesn't mean in the right hands any other CMS can achieve the same or better. EE can deliver perfect permalinks, but you will usually have to develop for this. One key aspect Wordpress has over EE is speed, again out of the box Wordpress usually delivers faster content, which is known to improve SEO scores. But again, this can be counted in EE by correct coding and utilising caching mechanism. The amount of effort you put in reaps rewards.